# rename and join multiple computer in csv files by IP address automatically using script powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, dns, ip-address, windows-server

i want to rename and join multiple computer in csv files,knowing IP address 
 for each computer automatically using script powershell

Comment: can any one help me for this situation

Comment: While you aren't a **new** user, please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [SO] isn't a free script writing service. ***Own research*** and code attempts are expected. [Edit] the question to include **your** code in a [mcve].

Comment: Something like: `$File1 | Join $File2 -On IPAddress`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026